# How to say "I took your class last year" to a teacher

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, verbes

I am unfamiliar with the grammar and would like to tell my teacher that I was in her class last year since she doesn't seem to remember me. How could I add the name of this class in the sentence as well? Would "J'ai pris votre cours de français l'année dernière" be accepted or are there better ways to state it?

Comment: *J'ai suivi votre cours*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to say that.

This is the simplest way to put it, as this [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37625/how-to-say-i-took-your-class-last-year-to-a-teacher#comment75286_37625) shows; but that will presume that the teacher knows already what course you are talking about; that is, this must have been introduced already in the conversation, as that teacher has certainly taught several courses;

- J'ai suivi votre cours.

A formulation that leaves nothing to be guessed could be as follows;

- L'année dernière, j'étais une des élèves de votre classe de français (de première/de terminale/etc.)
- J'étais dans votre classe de français (de première/de terminale/etc.) l'année dernière
- J'étais l'une des élèves à qui vous faisiez cours l'année dernière en classe de français (de première/de terminale/etc.)
- Je suivais/J'ai suivi vos cours de français (de première/de terminale/etc.) l'année dernière

If you leave out the complement between the parentheses the constructions are still correct. In fact any one of the complements can be left out. For instance, if you've made known to her which class it was and which year you can say "J'étais une de vos élèves.".

Answer (score 4):

What I would say is :

- J'ai **suivi** votre cours de français l'année dernière

*To take a class* is commonly rendered by *suivre un cours*.